# Node express + websockets with REST route to send/receive websocket messages

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

Using node, I'm trying to create a server in express with a route for websockets and a REST route to send and receive websocket messages. Basically, it should work like this:

1. A client connects to the server via http://localhost:3000/client.

   - The server returns a JS script
   - The script sets a cookie and establishes a websocket connection back to the server via ws://localhost:3000/websocket
   - The script is also set to reply to websocket messages with `document.cookie`
   - The websocket connection assigns a UID to the client
2. A `GET` request is made by a different system to http://localhost:3000/api?uid= (clientUID = someUID in this example)

   - The server loops through all websocket clients to find the correct client/UID
   - A message is sent to the client
   - The client responds with `document.cookie`
   - ***The server responds to the `GET` request with the message returned to the websocket server***

The last part is what isn't working. How can I capture the message returned to the websocket server and send it as a response to requests to the `/api` route?

```
const express = require('express');
const WebSocketServer = require('ws');
const http = require("http");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = 3000;

server.listen(port);
const wss = new WebSocketServer.Server({ server: server, path: '/websocket' });

// Each new websocket will be given a UID. This example uses a static UID of
// `someUID` for convenience
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws, req) { 
    ws.uid = 'someUID';

    ws.on("message", data => {
        // I want to send this data as a response to calls to `/api`
        console.log(`${data}`);
    });
 });

// This route sends a message to the client specified by the `uid` URL param.
// The client will respond (above) with the value of `document.cookie`
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    wss.clients.forEach(function (client) {
        if (client.uid == req.query.uid) {
            // I want to send the response of this message via `res.send()`
            client.send();
        }
    });
});

// Set up a client with a cookie and establish a websocket connection. When the
// client receives a message, it should return document.cookie.
app.get('/client', (req, res) => {
    res.send(' \
        <script> \
        document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue;"; \
        let url = "ws://localhost:3000/websocket"; \
        let connection = new WebSocket(url); \
        connection.onmessage = (e) => { \
            connection.send(document.cookie); \
        } \
        </script> \
    ')
});
```